Custom Preview Function in GrapesJS Page Builder
I have successfully implemented a page builder using the GrapesJS tool, and it's functioning as expected. However, I'm looking to enhance the user experience by adding a custom preview function that allows me to review the customized results without relying on the default preview in GrapesJS. Can anyone provide guidance on how to implement a custom preview functionality? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have the same question
